# The landing velocity of an airplane is 100 mi/hr. Constant deceleration and comes to a stop after traveling 1/4 mile. Find the deceleration.

Tags: derivatives

Please could someone confirm that my calculations and answer is correct.

The landing velocity of an airplane (i.e., the velocity at which it touches the ground) is 100 mi/hr. It decelerates at a constant rate and comes to a stop after traveling  mile along a straight landing strip. Find the deceleration or the negative acceleration.

$a=-c$

$v=-ct+100$

$s=-\frac{1}{2}ct^2+100t$

at $\frac{1}{4} = s, -c=0$

$\frac{1}{400}=t$ at $s=\frac{1}{4}$

at $t=\frac{1}{400}$ $v=0$

Therefore,

$0=-c\frac{1}{400}+100$

$c=40000$

$a=40000 miles/hour^2$

Comment: There is a shortcut formula: $v^2-v_0^2=2as$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At, $s = \frac{1}{4}, v = 0$, find time taken to get to $v = 0$

So, $v = 0 = -ct+100, t = \frac{100}{c}$

$\frac{1}{4} = - \frac{c}{2} (\frac{100}{c})^2 + \frac {100^2}{c}$

$\frac{1}{4} = \frac {100^2}{2c}$

$c = 2 \times 100^2$

Comment: Thank you, perfectly clear.

Comment: This is your mistake $\frac{1}{4} = s, -c=0$

The acceleration is not $0$ until "after" it comes to rest.

Comment: @OpenSauce you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your line $\frac14=s,-c=0$. I understand why $s=1/4$, but why is $-c=0$ is unclear to me.

Here is how I would approach it. Assuming constant deceleration $a=-c$ and the terminal time is $T$, the first equation implies
$$
v(t) = v_0 + at = 100 - ct \implies 0 = 100 - cT \iff T = \frac{100}{c}.
$$
The second equation says
$$
s(t) = 100t - \frac{ct^2}{2}
$$
but we want this at terminal time $T$, then
$$
\frac14
 = s(T) = s(100/c) = 100 \frac{100}{c} - \frac{c}{2} \left(\frac{100}{c}\right)^2
 = \frac{100^2}{2c}.
$$
You can easily solve this for $c$, can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you, $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{100^2}{c}$ $c=2*100^2$

Comment: @OpenSauce correct :)